# I want to navigate to the details of a product but it displays <QuerySet [<Product: Tshirt>]> and does not show any information Django ORM Python

Tags: python, django, orm

> When i click on the provided link it must show the products related to the particular shop but i get an error Unsupported lookup 'product_name' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
>
> Please suggest on this
>
> product_name is the foreign key for ProductDetails and shop is the foreign key for Products
>
> this is the template

`<strong><a href="{{partone}}">{{tut.product_description}}</a></strong>`

> Views.py

```
    # first check to see if the url is in categories.

    categories = [c.shop_slug for c in Shop.objects.all()]
    if single_slug in categories:
        matching_series = Product.objects.filter(shop_name__shop_slug=single_slug)
        series_urls = {}

        for m in matching_series.all():
            part_one = Product.objects.filter(product_name=m.product_name)
            series_urls[m] = part_one

        return render(request=request,
                      template_name='products/shop_products.html',
                      context={"product_name": matching_series, "part_ones": series_urls})
    
    product_details = [t.test_something for t in ProductDetails.objects.all()]
    if single_slug in product_details:
        this_product = ProductDetails.objects.get(test_something = single_slug)

        return render(request, 'products/product_details.html',{"product":this_product})

    return HttpResponse(f"{single_slug} does not correspond")
```

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# For shop in the beginning


# class ShopType(models.Model):
#     shop_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#     shop_type_description = models.TextField()

#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.shop_type


class Shop(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shop_location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shop_opening_time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    shop_slug = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    # shop_type = models.ForeignKey(
    #     ShopType, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    shop_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', null=True, blank=True)
    shop_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shop_description = models.TextField()
    shop_added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name


class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    product_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='products', null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    product_slug = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    product_added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    shop_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Shop, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class ProductDetails(models.Model):
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    test_something = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_something
```

When i click on the shop it displays related products. Now when i click on products i want to display the product details related.

> I am also trying to link the product to its details product_details = [t.test_something for t in ProductDetails.objects.all()] if single_slug in product_details: this_product = ProductDetails.objects.get(test_something = single_slug) return render(request, 'products/product_details.html',{"product":this_product}) URL = **{{tut.product_description}}** but it returns corresponds to nothing. and in url a query set is shown. Can you help on this

Comment: I think you need to use ```matching_series = Product.objects.filter(shop_name__shop_slug=single_slug).all()```

Comment: It still doesn't work returns same

Comment: /%3CQuerySet%20[%3CProduct:%20Tshirt%3E]%3E HTTP/1.1" 200 50

Answer (score 0):

I think, design wise this view is not good. Because it is handling two scenarios. One is for Products and another is for Product detail. I would first suggest to use two views for this or combine two functionality together. Here is an example on how to combine them:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(Q(shop_name__shop_slug=single_slug)|Q(productdetails__test_something=singleslug))
return render(
    request=request,
    template_name='products/shop_products.html',
    context={"products": products, "slug":single_slug}
)

# template

{% for product in products %}
   <strong><a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">{{product.product_description}}</a></strong>
    {% for details in product.productdetails.all %}
         {{ details.text_something }}
    {% endfor %}
{% empty %}
   {{ slug }} not found
{% endfor %}
```

I am using [**`Q`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to do complex queries. Also I am getting Product Details from [**`reverse relationship`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/) between `Product` and `ProductDetails`. Also, this implementation suggests to implement [**`get_absolute_url`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) in Models.

Comment: <QuerySet [<Product: Milk>]> not found  I am still getting this as an output what might be the reason. @ruddra

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your rendered template please?

Comment: <QuerySet [<Product: Tshirt>]> not found  this is only being displayed

In url= http://127.0.0.1:8000/%3CQuerySet%20[%3CProduct:%20Tshirt%3E]%3E

Comment: Sorry to say, I do not think you are implementing the way suggested by answer. Because in the answer, there is no reference of queryset in template.